# A word for a person that is expected to respond (to a message)

Tags: phrases

I am really struggling to shorten and rephrase the following:
"The person who is expected to respond to the message"

The person invited is A, the person that will respond could be either A or B(someone on behalf of A), depending on the users choice. The response will be either an accept or reject.

It will be seen on a webpage and will need to be self-explanatory for the majority.

Thanks in advance! (as I have just given up after coming up with "respondee")

Comment: ***Invitee*** is the term you are after.

Comment: I think a little more context is probably needed here...
The person invited is A, the person that will respond could be either A or B, depending on the users choice.
So "invitee" would imply just person A.

Comment: In that case, you are supposed to add this context to your question. Person A is invited by B. Thus A is an invitee who is supposed to accept/reject the invitation. Not sure what you mean when you say " either A or B" can respond. You definitely need to expand on your scenario.

Comment: I think that @Mynamite supplies a very good answer below. But as a separate point, I wouldn't in this context, use *accept* and *reject* as nouns. I think you are talking about an *acceptance* and a *rejection*.

Answer (score 1):

**Respondent:**

> A person who replies to something, especially one supplying
>   information for a questionnaire or responding to an advertisement: out
>   of the many thousands of respondents to our questionnaire, under a
>   fifth were full-time housewives ([oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/respondent))

This word does also have a specific legal meaning:

> A party against whom a petition is filed, especially one in an appeal
>   or a divorce case. (Same source as above.)